# Parsing sql statement with regex in php

Tags: php, regex, yii

Let's say we have a sql statement like this:

```
SELECT age extra WHERE age > 5 AND extra BETWEEN 5 2 UNIQUE
```

-- Note : It's a new syntax.

This statement has 3 parts.

Select part:

```
SELECT age extra
```

Where part:

```
WHERE age > 5 AND extra BETWEEN 5 2 UNIQUE
```

Unique part:

```
UNIQUE
```

I just want to get these parts from string with a regex.

Have a good time!

Comment: @downvoter: why you voted down for it??

Comment: Downvotes is because lack of efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Well this regex will work for you.

```
(.*?)(?=\sWhere)\s(.*?(UNIQUE|$))
```

The respective groups will contain what you want